# How do I pass link ID to controller?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, parameter-passing

recently I've been trying to figure out this issue. Imagine a page with few links, each link is generated using a query that retrieves all the links from my `DB`. What I'm trying to do is when I click the link it loads a detail page of that exact link's ID within the `detail` view. Instead I'm getting the url with the ID attached to it. I think that this `.$row->id` is what's causing it, but I don't know how else to pass the ID to the controller. Below is my code.. Thank you in advance for reading and possibly helping.

**detail_v**

result() as $row): ?>
      id) ?>" target="_blank" class="mosaic-overlay">

**controller**

```
public function detail($id) {
 $this->load->model('Core_m');
 $page =$this->Page_model->get_page_by_id($id);
 $this->load->view('detail_v');
}
```

**Core_m**

```
public function get_page_by_id($id) {
 $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM (`page`) WHERE `id` = \"$id\" LIMIT 1");
 if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
  {
   return $query->row(); 
  }
 return false;
}
```

Also a second thing I can't seem to figure out is why clicking the link opens a new browser window instead of just forwarding to the new URL within the same window. Please if you have any ideas on how to solve either of these issues please let me know. All help is much appreciated.

Comment: Remove `target="_blank"` from the `<a>` tag, that'll keep it to the same window

Comment: <?php echo base_url('core/detail/'.$row->id) ?>
Look for /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using `target="_blank"` opens a new browser window
```

And `<?php echo base_url('core/detail/'.$row->id) ?>` Look for / ..
Helped??

Comment: Sweet. I apologize for not knowing about the `_blank`. My result is now `http://localhost:8888/core/detail/1` so I guess it does the trick. I'm gonna have to play around with it now. Thank you very much. I am not accepting the answer yet, because I might come back with one or two additional questions hoping you could answer them as well :) Hope it won't upset you.

Comment: All works as intended. Thank you so, so much. Have a nice day ;)